# Using R to reformat data from cross-tab to one-datum-per-line format

Tags: r, excel, data-structures, dataformat, tableau-api

I'm using R to pull in data through an API and merge all of it into a single table, which I then write to a CSV file. To graph it properly in Tableau, however, I need to prepare the data by using their reformatting tool for Excel to get it from a cross-tablulated format to a format where each line contains only one piece of data. For example, taking something from the format:

```
ID,Gender,School,Math,English,Science
1,M,West,90,80,70
2,F,South,50,50,50
```

To:

```
ID,Gender,School,Subject,Score
1,M,West,Math,90
1,M,West,English,80
1,M,West,Science,70
2,F,South,Math,50
2,F,South,English,50
2,F,South,Science,50
```

Are there any existing tools in R or in an R library that would allow me to do this, or that would provide a starting point? I am trying to automate the preparation of data for Tableau so that I just need to run a single script to get it formatted properly, and would like to remove the manual Excel step if possible.

Comment: See `reshape` , the reshape2 package, stack, and related functions.

Comment: Please try to make this question more specific or it is likely to be closed. For good reading about what you're trying to do in R search for tidy data by Hadley Wickham.

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising. Tried updating above to make it more specific.

Comment: Tableau is the gateway drug to R ;-) I was a very keen Tableau 5/6/7 user but I found myself needing to update charts regularly with new data; that often led to unwanted changes in the Tableau charts, especially with regard to labels and so on. I needed genuine reproducibility. That prompted me to look more closely at R and `ggplot2`, which turned out to be the right solution. Every chart I could do in Tableau I can reproduce in R. I no longer use Tableau except for completely ad hoc plots. Oh, and I found the cost of updating Tableau annually to be painful.

Comment: Very interesting. I am learning R and Tableau simultaneously. I find R very nice for processing data, but was leaning toward Tableau for all my visualizations since they can be quickly embedded in a blog with a high level of detail/interactivity, and because it lets me think on the fly far more than ggplot2 would. I haven't dug very deeply into ggplot2 yet though.

Comment: I still feel that Tableau is way better for **exploration** of data IF your data is in a format that Tableau likes. Once you have to start pre-processing with R or their reshape tool, you have lost a good deal of the fluidity that makes Tableau special. One day I found myself changing the layout of Excel worksheets to make importing to Tableau easier and realised that the visualization tail was wagging the data dog. Master both platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R and several other programs, this process is referred to as "reshaping" data. In fact, the Tableau page [that you originally linked to](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/preparing-excel-files-analysis) speaks of their "Excel Reshaper plugin".

In base R, there are a few functions to reshape data, such as the (notorious) `reshape()` function which takes panel data from a wide form to a long form, and `stack()` which creates skinny stacks of your data.

The "reshape2" package seems to be much more popular for such data transformations, though.
Here's an example of "melting" your sample data, which I've stored in a `data.frame` named "mydf":

```
library(reshape2)
melt(mydf, id.vars=c("ID", "Gender", "School"), 
     value.name="Score", variable.name="Subject")
#   ID Gender School Subject Score
# 1  1      M   West    Math    90
# 2  2      F  South    Math    50
# 3  1      M   West English    80
# 4  2      F  South English    50
# 5  1      M   West Science    70
# 6  2      F  South Science    50
```

---

For this example, base R's `reshape()` isn't really appropriate, but `stack()` is. Here, I've `stack`ed just the last three columns:

```
stack(mydf[4:6])
#   values     ind
# 1     90    Math
# 2     50    Math
# 3     80 English
# 4     50 English
# 5     70 Science
# 6     50 Science
```

To get the `data.frame` you are looking for, you would `cbind` the first three columns with the above output.

---

For reference, Hadley Wickham's [Tidy Data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) paper is a good entry point into thinking about how the structure of your data might facilitate further processing and visualization.